# I want to download Xcode that I deleted again. But when I open App Store and search for Xcode the download button is grey

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, data-transfer

When I downloaded it before I did it through App Store but now that doesn't work because of that the button is grey. Have tried to download Xcode through developer.apple but there it says that I don't have enough storage which I clearly do because I got 16 GB free. HELP

Answer (score 2):

16 GB might be enough to *download* Xcode, but it might not be enough to *install* Xcode.

Xcode is delivered as compressed `.dmg` or `.pkg` file (I can't remember quite which) and it would be uncompressed upon installation.

16 GB is not a lot of space to run macOS in general.

If you need more space, you might use an app such as [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) to see if there's anything taking up unexpected space.